# Automatically capitalize keywords (for SQL)?

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to automatically replace keywords like `select` with `SELECT`. Is there a package that does this in Atom?

I know that there's the package `pg-formatter`, which works great for `.sql` file. Unfortunately my SQL queries are usually embedded in `.py` files, which pg-formatter will mess up.

Comment: I've tested adding [python-sql][3] parse component to [beautify][2] package, details in the links. Works when your file is saved as .sql, in md catches syntax highlight in code blocks but doesn't capitalise.
[2]: https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify
[3]: https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse